# What's the correct syntax for any char in PHP regex? My example does not work

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have a piece of html code as string:

```
<input id="an_id" name="a_name" value="some_value" class="a_class" type="text"/>
```

I want to get rid of the name attribute and its value with a regex and preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/name\="(.*)"/', '', $html, 1);
```

But this outputs:

```
<input id="an_id" />
```

Can anybody help me? Why does it delete that much? The regex is `name` for the attribute and `(.*)` because I don't care what char is in the value. There can be anything.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @JohnConde entire pages? Yes, bad idea. A single tag like this? Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking to match *any* character, you're looking to many any character other than `"`. Also, the capture group `()` is not necessary since you're not using the value in the replacement, and I don't know why you're escaping `=` since it's not a special character.

```
preg_replace('/name="[^"]*"/', '', $html, 1);
```

Comment: The escaping of = was made by preg_quote() I think.

Comment: Well, the docs say it will do just that. Still weird though since `=` only ever occurs in a lookahead, but it's the third character in a 3-character sequence, `(?=...)`, and I don't see why it would ever need to be escaped... but such is the mystery of what goes on in a PHP dev's mind.

Answer (score 1):

Make it ungreedy (see [Possible Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

```
preg_replace('/name\="(.*)"/U', '', $html, 1);
```

Result:

```
<input id="an_id"  value="some_value" class="a_class" type="text"/>
```

Or as @John Conde commented, use a [DOM Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 1):

Primitive, but it should get you going.

```
<?php
function remove_attribute($attribute, $html) {
    return preg_replace(
        sprintf('~%s="[^"]+"\s?~', preg_quote($attribute)),
        null,
        $html
    );
}

$html = '<input id="an_id" name="a_name" value="some_value" class="a_class" type="text"/>';
echo remove_attribute('name', $html);
/*
    <input id="an_id" value="some_value" class="a_class" type="text"/>
*/
```